# Elasticsearch combined query and filter not giving correct resutls

Tags: json, elasticsearch, dsl

I'm trying to make a search page with extra filter items, but i can't get my query to work how i want it.

Here's the query example:

```
{
    "size": 25,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": {
        "_score": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "year": "2015"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "Sense"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want only results that are from 2015. Searching for title 'Sense' comes up with nothing, even though there is a row with the title 'Sense8'. If i search for Sense8, it returns the correct data, but not 'Sense'.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please mention the mapping of the index and if possible a JSON document which you are expecting to appear in the result.

Comment: I am using a wrapper for generating queries called BungieSearch, but I found that both _"term"_ filters and _"terms"_ filters require arrays. Checkout this SO answer: [link(]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363647/elasticsearch-the-terms-filter-raise-filter-does-not-support-mediatest)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use an [`ngram`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) or [`edge ngram`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) analyzer in your mapping. I wrote a blog post about using ngrams for autocomplete on the [Qbox blog](http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams) that goes through it some detail, but here is some code that might give you what you want:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
               "type": "edgeNGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "ngram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
          "properties": {
               "year":{
                   "type": "string"
               },
               "title":{
                   "type": "string",
                   "index_analyzer": "ngram_analyzer", 
                   "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
               }
           }
      }
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"year": "2015","title":"Sense8"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"year": "2014","title":"Something else"}

POST /test_index/_search
{
    "size": 25,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": {
        "_score": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "year": "2015"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "Sense"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "_source": {
               "year": "2015",
               "title": "Sense8"
            },
            "sort": [
               0.30685282
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You can run the code in your browser here:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4f72c182db2017ac7d32077af16cbc3528cb79f0