# Elasticsearch the terms filter raise "filter does not support [mediatest]"

Tags: json, elasticsearch, dsl

my query is like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "online": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "mediaType": "flash"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it raise a QueryParsingException ***[[comos_v2] [terms] filter does not support [mediaType]]***,of which the field "mediaType" exactly does not exist in mapping.
my question is why term filter does not raise the Exception?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The above is not a valid Query DSL. In the above [Terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) the values to  "mediaType"  field should be an array

It should be the following :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "online": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "mediaType": ["flash"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its 2021 I'm using .keyword for an exact text match but you can just as easily omit:

```
{"query":
  {"bool":
    {"must":
      [
        {"term":
          {"variable1.keyword":var1Here}
        },
        {"term":
          {"variable2.keyword":var2Here}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simply a matter of "term" vs "terms". Very easy to miss the plural / single aspect of it.

I had a very similar error with this query, in which I was trying to delete a specific zone:

```
'{"query":{"terms":{"zoneid":25070}}}'
```

I was getting an error when I ran the above query.

As soon as changed "terms" to "term" the query executed with no issues, like this:

```
'{"query":{"term":{"zoneid":25070}}}'
```